# Using a pl sql variable in sql select value

Tags: select, plsql

I'm having a function where I would like to get the info from the table based of the parameter.

p_text is something like 'name' , or 'email' or 'birthday'  so in my cursist table that would be like calling the select cursist.name , cursist.email or cursist.birthday.

get_cursist_info(p_app => :APP_USER, p_text => 'name')

this is my function:

```
create or replace function get_cursist_info(p_app in varchar2, p_text in varchar2)
return varchar
is
v_userid varchar(200);
v_text varchar(200);
v_test varchar(200):= p_text;

begin

v_userid := get_cursist_id2(p_app);

select v_test
into v_text
from cursist
where cursist.cursistid = v_userid;

return v_text;
end get_cursist_info;
```

All it does now is getting the variabele v_test back (name) instead of the cursists name(Dave).

Isnt it possible to use a pl sql variable in the select? I don't really feel like making 8 functions for this.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without dynamic sql which is less efficient by using CASE clause:

```
select CASE v_test
        WHEN 'name' THEN name
        WHEN 'email' THEN email
        WHEN 'birthday' THEN birthday
        ELSE null
       END
into v_text
from cursist
where cursist.cursistid = v_userid;
```

Comment: I'm going to try that out. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: It worked! but do i need to write and other function to get number values?

Comment: You dont't have to write other functions but only modify this. I think the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966270/how-to-define-a-pl-sql-function-with-dynamic-return-types-in-oracle

Comment: Thanks it's now working perfectly ! I'm new to apex/pl sql.. I written multiple functions first to get the name, another one to get the email.. now i'm having it all in one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your query dynamically:

```
create or replace function get_cursist_info(p_app in varchar2, p_text in varchar2)
    return varchar
is
  v_userid varchar2(200);
  v_text   varchar2(200);
  v_test   varchar2(200):= p_text;
  v_sql    varchar2(1000);
begin

  v_userid := get_cursist_id2(p_app);

  v_sql := 'select cursist.' || v_test || ' from cursist where cursist.cursistid = ' || v_userid;
  execute immediate v_sql into v_text;

  return v_text;
end get_cursist_info;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
 Error ERR-9132 Error in PLSQL expression for item default code, item=P4_NAAM, the code in the page item is still : get_cursist_info(p_app => :APP_USER, p_text => 'naam')

Comment: Ok, there was a small typo, if have updated my answer

Comment: I see 3 problems here: dynamic sql is less efficient in most cases than static sql; there is no binding variable v_userid which additionaly decrease performance; it's less secure than static sql. I wouldn't say there is need to use dynamic sql in this case but it's possibility usage